# Calling a function for a drawn line on a mobile screen

Tags: android, gestures

I need a code for making a behavior for a line with different angles.
I mean that, if a user draws a Horizontal line on screen, my app runs a special function that I want.
If the user draws a line with any angle, the device can get it and make an output for it.
I mean: basing on what the user draws on the screen, an action is performed (for example, if I draw a z shape which is a shape with 2 horizontal line and 1 diagonal line, the app will save it).

```
package com.example.hi;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use GestureOverlayView to solve your purpose. Check and go through following links

http://www.intertech.com/Blog/android-gestureoverlayview-to-capture-a-quick-signature-or-drawing/

http://sampleprogramz.com/android/textureview.php

Answer (score 0):

That's called *gestures*.

You can use the Android Gesture Builder from the Android SDK samples.

You should be able to create the app from the sample, run it, create the custom gestures you want (circular clockwise and circular counter clockwise), and then get the gestures raw file from the device/emulator internal storage (it is created by the app after you make the gestures).

With that, you can import it to your project and use the Gesture Library to intercept, register and recognize the specific gestures. You basically add an overlay layout where you want the gesture to be captured and then you decide what to do with it.

See more in depth, step-by-step guide with detailed code in the following link: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Implementing_Android_Custom_Gesture_and_Pinch_Recognition